# Convert string in to date in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I need to Convert this string into date in iOS 2013-11-23T18:30:00.000+0000

I have written this code but always return nil

```
- (NSDate*) textForDueDate
{
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2013-11-23T18:30:00.000+0000"];
    return date;

}
```

Comment: Well, `2013-11-23T18:30:00.000+0000` is not even close to match `MM/dd/YYYY` so what did you expect?

Comment: hmmm your are right i want to get this sting in month/date/year date format

Comment: Useful for date formats http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2013-11-23T18:30:00.000+0000"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: Good ase hi mehanat karate raho :) Manish Jain